# CSS on button input cancel the prop disabled property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I made some CSS style for input button. After doing it, the `prop('disabled',true)` is not working for me (it used to work before the CSS changes)

HTML code:

```
<div id="navigation">
<button id="nextButton" type="button" name="nextButton">Next</button>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#nextButton').prop('disabled',true);
```

CSS code:

```
button{
    background:    #cfe2f3;
    background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfe2f3, #d0e0e3);
    background:    linear-gradient(#cfe2f3, #d0e0e3);
    border:        0.5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:         #000;
    display:       inline-block;
    padding:       8px 20px;
    font:          normal 700 18px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
    text-align:    center;
    text-shadow:   none;
}
```

My propose it to disable the press on the Next button

Comment: Can you do a Plunkr with this?

Comment: Well, the button is disabled. I think what you mean is that, it doesn't look disabled, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add some CSS to the disabled state:

```
button:disabled {
    // your css rules
}
```

Comment: After added the following: button:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}, it worked.

Comment: This is absolutely correct for `button` elements and other inputs that support a `disabled` state.  In case anyone stumbles on this but they are trying to apply it to anchor elements (`<a></a>`) it does not work, presumably because anchor elements are not supposed to be disabled/disableable.

Answer (score 0):

it is working.try this.I have linked jquery online

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  #one{
   background:    #cfe2f3;
    background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfe2f3, #d0e0e3);
    background:    linear-gradient(#cfe2f3, #d0e0e3);
    border:        0.5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:         #000;
    display:       inline-block;
    padding:       8px 20px;
    font:          normal 700 18px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
    text-align:    center;
    text-shadow:   none;
  }
 </style>

  




<body>

 <input type="button" id="one" name="button" value="button">
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#one").prop('disabled',true).css({"opacity":"0.6"});
     $("#one").on('click',function(){
      alert(" I am enable");
     })
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

try it with changing 'disabled' to 'enable', if it is enable, you may see an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to button as well when you make it disable so it will be confirm that button is disabled

```
        $('#nextButton').css('border','1px solid red');
        $('#nextButton').prop('disabled',true);
```

Hope so it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable a button by using below mentioned steps.

Say your button class name = setAlg

Step 1:

Using Jquery attr Attribute :

```
$('.setAlg').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Step 2:

Using Jquery addClass CSS Class :

```
$('.setAlg').addClass('disabled');
```

Step 3 :

Then by Declaring CSS Style Class :

```
<style type="text/css">
        .disabled
        {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 burlyWood;
            cursor: default !important;
        }
  </style>
```